LWC : [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'write')]
I have following LWC component which keeps throwing " [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'write')]" error.
I have tried everything to check that record is being pulled and new window is being opened.
But error persists.
I am unclear what I am doing wrong.
Any help is appreciated.
Below is the js code
        import { LightningElement, api, wire, track} from 'lwc';
        import {getRecord} from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
        
        const FIELDS = [
            'Audit_Log__r.Comp_Run_Date__c',
            'Audit_Log__r.Name',
            'Audit_Log__r.Editorial_Approver__c',
            'Audit_Log__r.Submitter_Name__c',
            'Audit_Log__r.Financial_Approver__c',
            'Audit_Log__r.Number_of_Records__c',
            'Audit_Log__r.Total_Amount__c',
            'Audit_Log__r.Total_Amount_Finance__c',
            'Audit_Log__r.Total_Amount_Foundry__c'
        ];
    
    export default class CashflowAuditTrailButton extends LightningElement {
    
    @api recordId;
    @track error;
    @track loading = true;
    recordData;
    

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS})
    record({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.error = undefined;
            this.loading = false;
            this.recordData = data;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.loading = false;
            this.recordData = undefined;
        }
    }
    handleClick() {
        if (this.recordData) {     console.log(this.recordData);
            const recordData = this.recordData.fields;
            const formattedData = `
            <h1>Audit Log</h1>
            <p><strong>Comp Run Date:</strong> ${recordData.Comp_Run_Date__c.value}</p>
            <p><strong>Comp Submitter:</strong> ${recordData.Submitter_Name__c.value}</p>
            <p><strong>Editorial Approver:</strong> ${recordData.Editorial_Approver__c.value}</p>
            `;

            const newWindow = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=600,height=400');
            if(newWindow){
                console.log('new window opened');
                console.log(formattedData);
                setTimeout (() => {
                newWindow.document.write(formattedData);
                newWindow.document.close();
                }, 0);
            }else{
                alert('Unable to open new window.Please check browser settings.');
            }
        } else {
            alert('Record data not available');
        }
    }
}

Despite all my efforts, error keeps popping up.



window.open returns a proxy object, depending on if you're using Locker Service or Lightning Web Security. The Locker API Viewer shows that window.open is supported, and the LWS Distortion Viewer says:

The window.open() method loads the specified resource into a new or
existing browsing context with the specified name. If the name doesn't
exist, then a new browsing context is opened in a new tab or a new
window, and the specified resource is loaded into it.
This new browsing context isn’t sandboxed properly and malicious code
can access system mode, so Lightning Web Security distorts the window
object returned.
Distorted Behavior
The returned window object has the same distortions applied to it as the originating sandbox.

What does this mean for your code? The newWindow variable contains a secure window that doesn't allow full access to all properties, as a security measure. What you have access to depends on the security model (LS or LWS), but either way, when you run into this kind of problem, it usually means that the security layer is preventing unsafe code from executing.
You'll need to use a different design that is compatible with the built-in security. Either create a Visualforce page that you can pop up in a new window with the details, use lightning-modal to show it inside the same window, or some other technique.

Thanks sfdcfox for that detailed response. Although I didn't fully understand what it means to  " security layer is preventing unsafe code from executing". I'll take your advise and instead either create a LWC to just display the values in desired format rather than a pop-up window or use visualforce.
